# Result of adding two numbers in Javascript is wrong on apache but not with artisan server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache, laravel-5, ampps

I've found a weird behavior of a site that I'm developing. It is being developed using Laravel 5.8 and uses the React preset to build all the front end. This project has a section of stats, and in some of them you need to show a `total` field.
When I use the `php artisan serve` to run my project, and access the stats, the results are displayed and calculated correctly. The problem comes when I deploy this site on Apache using AMPPS. When I do this, the total is calculated as a string, so for example, if I have a sum of `1+0`, instead of get a 1, I'm getting a `10`. It is concatenating the integers as strings.

This is the result when I'm using the `php artisan serve`
[image: This is the result when I'm using the <code>php artisan serve</code>]

And this one when I use apache: 
[image: And this one when I use apache]

This is my client code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.statsRoute = 'attendants/classification';
    this.state = {
        barData: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: [],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverBackgroundColor: [],
                    data: []
                }
            ],
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                }
            },
            tableRepresentation: {
                header: ['Clasificación', 'Número de Asistentes'],
                rows: []
            }
        },
        // Pie chart data
        pieData: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: [],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverBackgroundColor: [],
                    data: [],
                    total: 0
                }
            ],
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'bottom',
                },
                tooltips: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                            let dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                            let currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index].toFixed(2);
                            let label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                            return ` ${label}: ${currentValue}%`;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            tableRepresentation: {
                header: ['Clasificación', 'Porcentaje'],
                rows: []
            }
        }
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.statService.getStats(this.statsRoute)
        .then(res => {
            let total = 0;
            let barData = this.state.barData;
            let pieData = this.state.pieData;
            let colors = this.props.randomColorService.getArrayOfColors(res.length);

            for ( let i = 0; i < res.length; i++ ) {
                let item = res[i];

                total += item.count;
                barData.tableRepresentation.rows.push([
                    item.classification,
                    item.count
                ]);

                barData.labels.push(item.classification);
                barData.datasets[0].data.push(item.count);
                pieData.datasets[0].data.push(item.count * 100);
            }

            // Assign labels and colors to pie chart
            pieData.labels = barData.labels;
            barData.datasets[0].backgroundColor = colors['withAlfa'];
            barData.datasets[0].hoverBackgroundColor = colors['withoutAlfa'];

            // Assign colors to bar chart
            pieData.datasets[0].backgroundColor = colors['withAlfa'];
            pieData.datasets[0].hoverBackgroundColor = colors['withoutAlfa'];

            for ( let i = 0; i < pieData.datasets[0].data.length; i++ ) {
                pieData.datasets[0].data[i] /= total;
                let value = pieData.datasets[0].data[i];
                pieData.tableRepresentation.rows.push([
                    pieData.labels[i],
                    `${value.toFixed(2)}%`
                ]);
            }

            barData.tableRepresentation.rows.push([
                "",
                `Total: ${total}`
            ]);

            this.setState({
                barData: barData,
                pieData: pieData
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

And I doubt this is a problem from the backend, because when I do the query I got a JSON like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "item": "Invitado",
            "count": 6
        },
        {
            "item": "Asistente",
            "count": 7
        }
    ]
}
```

So, the backend does not make the total sum, I do that on the client.

Why this behaviour only happens when I'm using apache as server?

Comment: Are you sure Apache is doing this, and not your react frontend? PHP has 2 different operators for concatenation (`.`) and addiction (`+`)

Comment: Yes I'm sure, because I don't get the total from the database, I calculate the total on the front end.

Comment: Might help if you can sure your front end code

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that you are using different versions of PHP, or that both of your servers are using different line encodings

Comment: Tell React to treat the JSON results as integers before doing the addition. Find `total += item.count;` - change to `total += parseInt(item.count);`

Comment: The result comes as an integer. I know that a parseInt could solve this, but, The real question is why this is happening? Why on the apache server?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `total += item.count;` with `total += +item.count;`.

`+` will explicitly convert it into int, right now for the apache version, the numbers are being treated as strings and are concatenated rather than added.

Comment: Is there a reason why this happening?